# Persistent key value store for Python using SQLite3

Tags: python, database, python-2.x, sqlite

This is a module to implement a key value store in Python using SQLite3. Originally written to allow sharing of configuration among multiple threads that are already sharing a SQLite3 database, I have generalized for most use cases. The interface in Python is as similar to dictionary objects as possible.

Differences from a normal python dictionary:

- a file and path must be provided on creation
- it's not possible to create a kvstore literally as you would a dict

The following dictionary methods are not implemented:

- `fromkeys(seq[, value])`
- `viewitems()`
- `viewkeys()`
- `viewvalues()`

I would be grateful for any review, particularly considering the following areas:

- Corner cases I've missed in my testing
- Anything that could be more pythonic
- Anything that could be more efficient (note that it is intended that the whole dictionary not be loaded into memory where possible, as large dictionaries / low memory systems are a potential target)

```
import sqlite3
import json
import UserDict

try:
    from cPickle import Pickler, Unpickler
except ImportError:
    from pickle import Pickler, Unpickler

try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO


class sqlite3keyvaluestore(UserDict.DictMixin):

    def __init__(self, filenameandpath, tablename='ApplicationConfiguration', serialisationtype='json'):
        """filenameandpath - the name and path to the file
        tablename - the name of the table to create (or use) in the database (this allows the file to be used for other purposes with control over potential name clashes
        serialisationtype - either 'json' or 'pickle', defaults to 'json' - the method used to serialise the value in the database"""
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(filenameandpath)
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()
        self.filenameandpath = filenameandpath
        self.serialisationtype = serialisationtype
        self.tablename = tablename
        query = "SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='%s';" % self.tablename
        self.cur.execute(query)
        if not self.cur.fetchall():
            query = """CREATE TABLE `%s` (
                                    `k` TEXT,
                                    `v` TEXT,
                                    PRIMARY KEY(k)
                                );""" % self.tablename
            self.cur.execute(query)
            self.con.commit()
            print 'created table'
        if serialisationtype == 'json':
            self.tostring = self._jsontostring
            self.fromstring = self._jsonfromstring
        elif serialisationtype == 'pickle':
            self.tostring = self._pickletostring
            self.fromstring = self._picklefromstring

    def _pickletostring(self,value):
        f = StringIO()
        p = Pickler(f, 0)
        p.dump(value)
        return f.getvalue()

    def _picklefromstring(self,value):
        f = StringIO(value)
        return Unpickler(f).load()

    def _jsontostring(self,value):
        return json.dumps(value)

    def _jsonfromstring(self,value):
        return json.loads(value)

    def keys(self):
        query = "SELECT k FROM %s" % self.tablename
        self.cur.execute(query)
        return [item[0] for item in self.cur.fetchall()]

    def values(self):
        query = "SELECT v FROM %s" % self.tablename
        self.cur.execute(query)
        return [self.fromstring(item[0]) for item in self.cur.fetchall()]

    def items(self):
        query = "SELECT k, v FROM %s" % self.tablename
        self.cur.execute(query)
        return [(item[0],self.fromstring(item[1])) for item in self.cur.fetchall()]

    def __len__(self):
        query = "SELECT Count(*) FROM %s" % self.tablename
        self.cur.execute(query)
        return self.cur.fetchone()[0]

    def has_key(self, key):
        query = "SELECT k FROM %s WHERE k = ?" % self.tablename
        self.cur.execute(query, (key,))
        return bool(self.cur.fetchone())

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        query = "SELECT v FROM %s WHERE k = ?" % self.tablename
        self.cur.execute(query,(key,))
        result = self.cur.fetchone()
        if result:
            return self.fromstring(result[0])
        else:
            raise KeyError

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        query = "INSERT OR REPLACE INTO %s (k, v) VALUES (?, ?);" % self.tablename
        self.cur.execute(query,(key, self.tostring(value)))
        self.con.commit()

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        if not self.has_key(key):
            raise KeyError
        else:
            query = "DELETE FROM %s WHERE k = ?" % self.tablename
            self.cur.execute(query,(key,))
            self.con.commit()

    def close(self):
        self.con.close()

    def __del__(self):
        self.con.close()

    def clear(self):
        query = "DELETE FROM %s" % self.tablename
        self.cur.execute(query)

    def copy(self):
        return dict(self.items())

    def iter(self):
        return self.iterkeys()

    def __iter__(self):
        return self.iterkeys()

    def iteritems(self):
        def resultfunction(result):
            return (result[0], self.fromstring(result[1]))
        return databaseiterator(self.filenameandpath, self.tablename, self.serialisationtype, "SELECT k, v FROM %s LIMIT 1 OFFSET " % self.tablename, resultfunction)

    def iterkeys(self):
        def resultfunction(result):
            return result[0]
        return databaseiterator(self.filenameandpath, self.tablename, self.serialisationtype, "SELECT k FROM %s LIMIT 1 OFFSET " % self.tablename, resultfunction)

    def itervalues(self):
        def resultfunction(result):
            return self.fromstring(result[0])
        return databaseiterator(self.filenameandpath, self.tablename, self.serialisationtype, "SELECT v FROM %s LIMIT 1 OFFSET " % self.tablename, resultfunction)


class databaseiterator:
    def __init__(self, filenameandpath, tablename, serialisationtype, query, resultfunction):
        """query should be in the form "SELECT <your code here> LIMIT 1 OFFSET "
        """
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(filenameandpath)
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()
        self.tablename = tablename
        self.query = query
        self.offset = 0
        self.resultfunction = resultfunction

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        query = self.query + str(self.offset) + ';'
        self.cur.execute(query)
        result = self.cur.fetchone()
        if result is None:
            raise StopIteration
        else:
            self.offset += 1
            return self.resultfunction(result)


def test1(database):
    """Testing: keys, values, clear, __setitem__, __getitem__"""
    database.clear()
    assert len(database.keys()) == 0
    assert len(database.values()) == 0
    assert len(database.items()) == 0
    database['hello'] = 'world'
    assert database['hello'] == 'world'
    assert len(database.keys()) == 1
    assert len(database.values()) == 1
    assert len(database.items()) == 1
    assert database.keys() == ['hello']
    assert database.values() == ['world']
    assert database.items() == [('hello','world')]
    assert len(database) == 1
    database.clear()
    assert len(database) == 0

def test2(database):
    """Testing: copy, setdefault, iter, iterkeys, iteritems, itervalues, pop, popitem"""
    database.clear()
    database['hello'] = 'world'
    assert database.copy() == {'hello':'world'}
    assert database.setdefault('hello') == 'world'
    assert database.setdefault('goodbye') == None
    database['goodbye'] = 'cruel world'
    iterator = database.iter()
    assert iterator.next() == 'hello'
    assert iterator.next() == 'goodbye'
    iterator = database.iteritems()
    assert iterator.next() == ('hello','world')
    assert iterator.next() == ('goodbye','cruel world')
    iterator = database.itervalues()
    assert iterator.next() == 'world'
    assert iterator.next() == 'cruel world'
    assert database.pop('hello') == 'world'
    assert database.pop('non-existent key','default response') == 'default response'
    assert database.popitem() == ('goodbye','cruel world')

def test3(database):
    """Testing: __repr__, __cmp__"""
    database.clear()
    database['hello'] = 'world'
    database['goodbye'] = 'cruel world'
    assert str(database) == "{u'hello': u'world', u'goodbye': u'cruel world'}"
    assert database == {'hello':'world','goodbye':'cruel world'}
    database.clear()

def test4(database):
    """Testing get"""
    database.clear()
    database['hello'] = 'world'
    database['goodbye'] = 'cruel world'
    assert database.get('hello') == 'world'
    database.clear()

def test5(database):
    """Testing: update"""
    database.clear()
    database.update([('hello','world'),('goodbye','cruel world')])
    assert database == {'hello':'world','goodbye':'cruel world'}
    database.clear()



def main():
    filename = 'testconfigdatabase.sqlite'

    kvdatabase = sqlite3keyvaluestore(filename, tablename='ApplicationConfiguration', serialisationtype='json')

    test1(kvdatabase)
    test2(kvdatabase)
    test3(kvdatabase)
    test4(kvdatabase)
    test5(kvdatabase)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Did you consider using the built-in [`dbm`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dbm.html)?

Answer (score 3):

First, the obligatory pointer to [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). In particular, your class names and some docstrings do not follow it. Variable names and line lengths arguably as well.

Next, a couple of specific cases where you could make the code clearer or more efficient:

---

```
def has_key(self, key):
    query = "SELECT k FROM %s WHERE k = ?" % self.tablename
    self.cur.execute(query, (key,))
    return bool(self.cur.fetchone())
```

You should define the lower level method `__contains__` instead. `DictMixin` will use that to define `has_key` and that way you are sure to get efficient `in` testing. Speaking of which:

```
def __delitem__(self, key):
    if not self.has_key(key):
        raise KeyError
    else:
        query = "DELETE FROM %s WHERE k = ?" % self.tablename
        self.cur.execute(query,(key,))
        self.con.commit()
```

I think more Pythonic would be:

```
def __delitem__(self, key):
    if key not in self:
        raise KeyError
    query = "DELETE FROM %s WHERE k = ?" % self.tablename
    self.cur.execute(query,(key,))
    self.con.commit()
```

However, beware. AFAICT, the item could have been deleted by another process in between checking whether it exists and deleting it. You should probably just delete the item and raise an error *if* that fails.

---

```
class databaseiterator:
    def __init__(self, filenameandpath, tablename, serialisationtype, query, resultfunction):
        """query should be in the form "SELECT <your code here> LIMIT 1 OFFSET "
        """
        self.con = sqlite3.connect(filenameandpath)
        self.cur = self.con.cursor()
        self.tablename = tablename
        self.query = query
        self.offset = 0
        self.resultfunction = resultfunction
```

You are saving some data that you never use. `self.con`, `self.tablename` never used after this. The whole parameter `tablename` is unused if you remove the assignment. `serialisationtype` already is. If you remove `serializationtype` from here, you can also remove `self.serialisationtype` from `sqlite3keyvaluestore.__init__`.

Comment: Thanks otus, some great feedback. On __delitem__, you are right that the item could be deleted by another process between checking whether it exists and deleting it. However, because of the way SQLite works (and I think relational databases generally), the delete command will not fail if there are no values present, and doesn't provide a return value. Hence the only way I can think of to emulate the behavior of a dictionary is to do the check first.

Comment: Also, are there any other specifics on PEP8 other than class names, docstrings, variable names and line lengths? (I have read PEP8, but have far from memorised it ;-)

Comment: @user3765127, those aren't enough? :) No, I think that's it PEP-wise. Regarding `__delitem__`, in that case I think it's OK, although you could just remove the check with probably no problems.

Comment: Docstrings are covered in company-specific style guides. Google, for instance uses napolean style: https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example_google.html